# DynamoDBMapper for java.time.LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, amazon-dynamodb

I'm utilizing java.time.LocalDateTime in my java application. I'm also trying to use `DynamoDBMapper` and via the annotation save the `LocalDateTime` variable. Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
DynamoDBMappingException: Unsupported type: class java.time.LocalDateTime
```

Is there a way to have this mapping without using `DynamoDBMarshalling`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No AWS DynamoDB Java SDK can't map java.time.LocalDateTime natively without using any annotation.

To do this mapping, you have to use [`DynamoDBTypeConverted`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html) annotation introduced in the version 1.11.20 of the AWS Java SDK. Since this version, the annotation [`DynamoDBMarshalling`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMarshalling.html) is deprecated.

You can do that like this:

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    @DynamoDBTypeConverted( converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class )
    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {

        return startTime;
    }

    ...

    static public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public String convert( final LocalDateTime time ) {

            return time.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime unconvert( final String stringValue ) {

            return LocalDateTime.parse(stringValue);
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, the stored dates are saved as string in the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format like that: `2016-10-20T16:26:47.299`.

Answer (score 3):

Despite what I said I found it simple enough to use `DynamoDBMarshalling` to marshal to and from a string. Here is my code snippet and an [AWS reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaArbitraryDataMappingHLAPI.html):

```
class MyClass {

    ...

    @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
    public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    ...
    static public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements DynamoDBMarshaller<LocalDateTime> {

        @Override
        public String marshall(LocalDateTime time) {
            return time.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDateTime unmarshall(Class<LocalDateTime> dimensionType, String stringValue) {
            return LocalDateTime.parse(stringValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the annotation [DynamoDBMarshalling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMarshalling.html) is deprecated, you can use the annotation [DynamoDBTypeConverted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTypeConverted.html) instead. See my answer for more information.